# css hover in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hover

Cant get this to work in IE, but works perfect Firefox, is this due to the way i have written my CSS?

Thanks

R

**CSS**

```
.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:26px;
    height:23px;
    background:  url(../images/arrows-3.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}

.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a:hover {
    display:block;
    width:26px;
    height:23px;
    background: url(../images/arrows-over-1.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
//Add Direction nav
if(settings.directionNav){ 
    slider.append(
        '<div class="nivo-directionNav">
            <a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a>
            <a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a>
        </div>'
    ); 
    //Hide Direction nav 
    if(settings.directionNavHide){ 
        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
        slider.hover( function(){ 
            $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
        },
        function(){ 
            $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide(); 
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Post your HTML markup as well. State how it shows now and how it should show. Also remove 'enter code here'

Comment: You don't have to repeat yourself, your `:hover` rule only needs the changed background, the rest will be applied from your previous rule.

Comment: Hi This works with Javascript code so its not in HTML

Comment: @Rifki You need to add the Javascript and the HTML the code is being applied to. If you can reproduce the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) then this will also help people answer your question. At the moment it is all guess work, especially since you do not explain what does not work in IE. Using the CSS you have provided, it all works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRkZ4/

Comment: Well at least show the generated HTML then, or the script that generates it. The CSS above seems fine.

Comment: Works with JavaScript code? how so? post some code please. PS. use colors rather than images to ensure its not just a path issue.

Comment: //Add Direction nav
        if(settings.directionNav){
            slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a></div>');
            
            //Hide Direction nav
            if(settings.directionNavHide){
                $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                slider.hover(function(){
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
                }, function(){
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                });
            }

Answer (score 2):

For reasons beyond human comprehension IE8 (possibly other versions of IE also) does not apply the `:hover` state unless a link has an associated `href` property.

This can be rectified by replacing:

```
//Add Direction nav
if(settings.directionNav){ 
    slider.append(
        '<div class="nivo-directionNav">
            <a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a>
            <a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a>
        </div>'
    ); 
    //Hide Direction nav 
    if(settings.directionNavHide){ 
        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
        slider.hover( function(){ 
            $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
        },
        function(){ 
            $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide(); 
        }); 
}
```

with

```
//Add Direction nav
if(settings.directionNav){ 
    slider.append(
        '<div class="nivo-directionNav">
            <a class="nivo-prevNav" href="#">'+ settings.prevText +'</a>
            <a class="nivo-nextNav" href="#">'+ settings.nextText +'</a>
        </div>'
    ); 
    //Hide Direction nav 
    if(settings.directionNavHide){ 
        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
        slider.hover( function(){ 
            $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
        },
        function(){ 
            $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide(); 
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Agree, this could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason this should not work in IE 8. Maybe your image path is incorrect.
Also you dont need to repeat porperties in :hover becouse everything is adepted from a-tag.

Try a backgroundcolor and i think it will work. Figure out your problem with the background-image if this works (red background-color on hover state):

```
.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:26px;
    height:23px;
    background:  url(../images/arrows-3.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}

.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a:hover {
    background: url(../images/arrows-over-1.png) no-repeat 0 0 #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For best design view in IE6 to 9 you must use javascript libraries below. just call these js only rest will do js.

- important:- these js must be called in head not in body of a file

  1. [htmlshiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) for html5 new tags
  2. [google js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) for IE
  3. [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) js for css3 new classes